# Mysql STR_TO_DATE give inconsistent result across different environment

Tags: mysql, docker, date

I am running into an inconsistent behaviour across two different Docker image with the STR_TO_DATE function. On running on a ubuntu box and the other one running on my Mac.

On Linux:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s');
+--------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s') |
+--------------------------------+
| 20:30:05                       |
+--------------------------------+

SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.19    |
+-----------+
```

On my Mac:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s');
+--------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s') |
+--------------------------------+
| NULL                           |
+--------------------------------+

SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.12    |
+-----------+

show warnings; 
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                     |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '203005' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Both running Mysql on a Docker image:

```
      docker_container:
        name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.0
```

Comment: Does `show warnings;` immediately after the str_to_date select tell you anything useful?

Comment: Are you sure you did not use a lower case `H` in the second environment?

Comment: Good idea @ysth, I've updated the question with the warnings. Nothing useful to me.

Comment: Nope both ```H``` in the different environment, I've updated the question with the select statement.

Comment: Is `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` different?  Shouldn't make any difference, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE` will return `NULL` if you have an incomplete datetime value (in your case, there's no date) and SQL MODE `NO_ZERO_DATE` is set (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)). For example:

```
SET @@sql_mode = ''
;
SELECT @@sql_mode, STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s') AS date
;
SET @@sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE'
;
SELECT @@sql_mode, STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s') AS date
;
SET @@sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE'
;
SELECT @@sql_mode, STR_TO_DATE('203005','%H%i%s') AS date
```

Output:

```
@@sql_mode          date
                    20:30:05
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE     20:30:05
NO_ZERO_DATE        null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ecJo6E5Q4VmCw4wb7JXcf3/1)

Comment: Thanks this was the good call. The variable sql_mode is however identical in both environment, so something mysterious remain.

Comment: @JulienGagnet you shouldn't accept the answer if it doesn't actually solve your problem. Have you checked both global (`@@GLOBAL.sql_mode`) and session (`@@SESSION.sql_mode`) sql_mode?

Comment: It does solve my problem, when I set ```SET @@sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE';```. However both ```sql_mode``` had the same value in both environment. And I was working with the same Docker image in the same environment.